# Jace, Cunning Castaway +1 Ability

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So anyone who has been looking at the spoilers for Ixalan has probably come to the conclusion that the Jace, Cunning Castaway + [Doubling Season](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoubling%20Season%5d) is ridiculously broken.

Following on from this combo, if I created an arbitrarily large number of Jace tokens (say 1,000) and some number (say 500) used their +1 ability, would they all stack meaning if I then connected with the opponent I could potentially deck myself? Or would I just draw a single card.

I'm wondering for the feasability of a [Laboratory Maniac](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLaboratory%20Maniac%5d) combo.

td;lr Is Jace, Cunning Castaway + [Doubling Season](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoubling%20Season%5d) + [Laboratory Maniac](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLaboratory%20Maniac%5d) possible?

Comment: To be fair, Doubling Season + Planeswalker is usually already broken.

Comment: Wow... there goes my chances of getting a Laboratory Maniac for my Niv Mizzet Commander Deck, However, Dat Jace Doh...

Comment: If you're looking to win on Laboratory Maniac, Cephalid Illusionist + Shuko is much lower mana cost and mono-colored.  Jace CC + Doubling Season seems better used to just make a couple million 2/2 illusions and attack with them next turn and not need a third card in the combo.

Comment: To be honest that was more of an example. I just like janky decks with alt win cons. I love simic edh with doubling seasons, so was just wondering whether feasible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this combo works. Jace, Cunning Castaway's first loyalty ability creates a delayed triggered ability, that triggers when your creatures deal combat damage to an opponent. If you resolve multiple copies of that loyalty ability, then when you deal combat damage to an opponent, each delayed triggered ability will trigger and resolve separately and you will draw a card then discard a card that many times.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, that combo would work to win you the game.**

Jace, Cunning Castaway's -5 ability and Doubling Season would allow you to create an arbitrary number of Jace copies. Those Jaces that didn't use an ability yet this turn can activate their +1 ability, and all of them would trigger on your combat damage. With Laboratory Maniac under your control and more Jace +1 triggers than cards in your library, you would win as soon as the (n+1)-th trigger has resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although the Labratory Maniac seems redundant. You can already get infinite creatures through Jace's second ability, so you can just swing in for a ton of damage with those and win.

Comment: To be fair, the Illusions don't have haste, so that approach requires you to wait a turn, while the Lab Maniac win can happen during the same turn's upkeep.